# Combining multiple functions

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a DNA transcription program but I'm having trouble with the way I'm doing it, I'm sure there's an easier way to do this but this was the first thing that came to my head but it's not working the way I want it to.

```
dnaToRna :: [Char] -> [Char]
dnaToRna [] = []
dnaToRna xs = reverse(transc xs)
    where transc = (replaceA . replaceT . replaceC . replaceG)
replaceA = map(\c -> if c == 'A' then 'U' else c)
replaceT = map(\c -> if c == 'T' then 'A' else c)
replaceC = map(\c -> if c == 'C' then 'G' else c)
replaceG = map(\c -> if c == 'G' then 'C' else c)
```

Here's the output:

```
*Main> let seq = "AAATGTTAGTACACTAAGG"
*Main> dnaToRna seq
"GGUUUGUGUUGUUUGUUUU"
```

I figure this is because the transc replaces the A, then checks the whole String and replaces the T, etc etc
Any tips?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you replace all the C's with G's then replace all the G's with C, your DNA will now only have C's. You need to transcribe each character as you go.

Comment: I suggest making a function with type `Char -> Char` which maps a given letter to its "opposite". Then you can map this function over the entire dna strand. Essentially, you need to combine all of your lambdas into a single function.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I needed it to be [Char] and a map with a new function would've made it give an error, I tried it before, maybe was doing something wrong but the guy down there already made it work :)

Comment: The given answer is exaclty what I had in mind. Notice that `transc :: Char -> Char` and is mapped once over the input list `[Char]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make one function which handles all of the `Char -> Char` conversions at once.

```
dnaToRna :: [Char] -> [Char]
dnaToRna = reverse . map transc
  where
    transc 'A' = 'U'
    transc 'T' = 'A'
    transc 'C' = 'G'
    transc 'G' = 'C'
    transc _   = error "Invalid DNA molecule"
```

To make this even safer, you could make it return a `Maybe [Char]` instead. The [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) function can also be used instead of using a custom mapping function.

```
dnaToRna :: [Char] -> Maybe [Char]
dnaToRna = mapM (`lookup` zip "ATCG" "UAGC") . reverse
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, that did it, I had tried doing something with map but was making a different function called transc but then it would let me map because of too few arguments....

Comment: IMO, you do the community a disservice by completely solving a problem like this for the OP.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm very choosy about only giving answers like this to people who've actually put in the effort and just need a small push. If you'd like though, I'd be happy to discuss the issue in chat.

Comment: @4castle You make a good point. The OP certainly has made an effort to solve the problem. I was trying to give him a slightly smaller push towards a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

@4castle's answer shows the right direction.

Since OP's problem has been solved i believe it would worth to show how to make it more efficient by using [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html) for the look ups. Also by using a [`foldl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl) we may skip the reversing job as well.

```
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M

dna2rna :: String -> String
dna2rna = foldl (\r c -> (M.findWithDefault '-' c m) : r) ""
          where m  = M.fromList $ zip "ATCG" "UAGC"

*Main> dna2rna "AAATGTTAGTACACTAAGG"
"CCUUAGUGUACUAACAUUU"
```

Comment: Thanks for ur solution, will look into it :)