# Haskell use map

Tags: haskell

I would like to know if it is possible to use a map in my code instead of being as it is. My code is to receive a `String`, replace some `Char`s with others and reverse it, but I wanted to use a map in this code.

```
transforme' ::[Char] -> [Char]
transforme'   = reverse'.condiçoes

condiçoes :: [Char] -> [Char]
condiçoes   = foldr (\x -> if
                x == 'A' then ('U':)
                else if x == 'T' then ('A':)
                else if x == 'C' then ('G':)
                else if x == 'G' then ('C':)
                else (x:)) []

reverse' :: [Char] -> [Char]
reverse' xs = foldr (\b f x -> f (b : x)) id xs []
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining multiple functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146630/combining-multiple-functions)

Answer (score 1):

You can first construct a "translation" function:

```
trns 'A' = 'U'
trns 'T' = 'A'
trns 'C' = 'G'
trns 'G' = 'C'
trns x = x
```

And ow we can use:

```
condiçoes = map trns
```

So we perform a mapping over the `trns` function.

Note that there is a [**`reverse :: [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reverse) builtin, or you can ue `foldl` for this:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' = foldl (flip (:)) []
```